# The calc routine using less

Tags: css, less, css-calc

Is there a way to use the css calc() routine using less?

If i go to http://less2css.org/  and I type the the following input (which is just a regular css rule):

```
width: calc(100% - 450px);
```

The output should be exactly the same (because it's regular css) however,

the css output which the less compiler is producing is `width: calc(-350%);`

Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Escape](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping) the value:

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 450px)";
```

Escaping is unnecessary in LESS 1.4 though, because calculations are only done when the calculation is surrounded by parentheses. For example:

```
prop: 20 + 10px;    ->  prop: 20 + 10px;
prop: (2 + 10px);   ->  prop: 12px;
prop: func(1 + 2);  ->  prop: func(1 + 2);
prop: func((1 + 2));->  prop: func(3);
```

Comment: +1 thanks,  also, is there any way to use less variables within the expression as well or is that pushing it?

Comment: @Danield You mean `~"calc(100% - @{varname})"`?

Comment: yes, where, varname is a less variable

Comment: @Danield Yes, the example I gave you works. It was not a question, but an answer disguised as a question ;)

Comment: wow that's great, one last thing: what if I want to do an operation with that variable, eg: i tried ~"calc(100% - @{varname}*3) but the css output didn't calculate the *3 part

Comment: @Danield Put the calculation outside the escaped string: `@varname: @othervarname * 3;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do calculations within the LESS expression (apart from the actual css calc) you can quickly get yourself in a big unreadable mess like this:

```
 @width: 85;
 left: ~'calc('((100vw - @width) / 2)~')';
```

This results in :

```
 left: calc( 7.5vw );
```

I couldn't find a way to do this without the spaces being added in.

So an easier to read method is to just create an intermediate variable:

```
 @left: ((100vw - @width) / 2);
 left: ~'calc(@{left})';
```

Which results in :

```
left: calc(7.5vw);
```

Comment: Why not this?
left: ~'calc(((100vw - @{width}) / 2))';